# zIndex is not working on android

Tags: android, css, react-native, overlap

[image]

As I want to overlap this icon with two other Views, as shown in the image. this code is working on IOS platform but not on android. please suggest if there is any solution for Android.

```
   var tabs = ['Activity', 'Files', 'People'];
   this.state = {
    tabs
  };
return (
  <Container style={{backgroundColor: '#F5F5F5'}}>
      <View style={styles.topStrip}>
          {
            this.state.tabs.map((tab, index) => (
              <View key={index} >
                <TouchableOpacity>
                  <Text style={styles.streamName}>{tab}</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
            ))
          }
        <View style={{position: 'absolute', backgroundColor: 'transparent', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', zIndex: 5, elevation: 24, marginTop: 15, marginLeft: 300}}>
          <EIcon size={40} color='#2196f3' name={'circle-with-plus'} />
         </View>
       </View>
     <View style={{zIndex: -1}}></View>
   </Container>
  );
 }
}
  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   topStrip: {
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
 streamName: {
   marginTop: 7,
   marginBottom: 6,
   flexDirection: 'row',
   alignSelf: 'center'
  }
 }
});
```

[image]

Comment: z-index not zIndex

Comment: @hanslutterf. this is a React Native application, you must write CSS properties with camelCase instead of hyphens

Answer (score 0):

```
<View
      style={{
        paddingLeft: ITEM_HEIGHT * 3,
        flex: 1,
        position: "absolute",
        top: 0,
        right: 0,
        bottom: 0,
        left: 0,
        zIndex: -1
      }}
    >
      <Image
        style={styles.centerCircle}
        resizeMode="contain"
        source={Images.ballSmall}
      />
    </View>
```

In android, to use zIndex you need css with position-properties with top,left,right,bottom css 
Tested On: Zenfone 3, Android 7, React Native 0.55.4

Answer (score 0):

This issue is not caused by `zIndex` (although it does cause problem on Android).

Your icon is put inside the upper container view. React Native on Android does not support `overflow: visible`. That's why you see your icon being clipped outside the container.

You may put the icon on the "page" component level to solve this issue.

You may also refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/50991892/6025730.