# React Native Android Clipping Children

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation, expo

I am creating a react native app using expo, and I am creating a dropdown in the header. On iOS the dropdown works as desired, and goes 'above' the main content, while on Android it is clipped or goes 'under'. I am not sure if in reality iOS is acting strange, or Android is.
[image: iOS vs Android]

The header is a custom headerTitle component, which holds the custom dropdown component (a view, which holds the dropdown items (Views with text and icons)

I am looking to get around this issue, and I have tried zIndex and absolute positioning (which I have read does not even work on android, but thought I would try), and that did not fix it (and caused other issues).

[image: With absolute positioning and zIndex]

Any tips, tricks, and better understanding of why this happens on iOS and Android would be greatly appreciated. I can post code if necessary as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React Native does not support `overflow: 'visible'` on Android.

A good example to look at for this is here: https://github.com/brentvatne/growler-prowler/blob/0eebfaae641a088b1a1fd7ffe552deeac914bffe/screens/BreweryListScreen.js#L70-L76

The key here is to render the menu component inside of a modal (in this case I'm using react-native-root-modal) in order to have it appear on top of the header.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Is there a specific reason overflow was not added to android, or is it something in the future? I will take a look at your example over the weekend.

Comment: From changelog of 0.57: Add Support for overflow style property    https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-releases/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#057